# Create vertical table in PHP

Tags: php, transpose

I have a array of row and column.

```
<?php 
  $rows=array(3); // rows 0 to 3
  $cols=array(3); // column 0 to 3

  );
?>
```

And i want to create a table according to following fashion with loop.

```
<table border="1px">
 <tr>
   <td>10</td> // 0 row digit of 1 column
   <td>20</td> // 0 row digit of 2 column
   <td>30</td> // 0 row digit of 3 column

 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>15</td> // 1 row digit of 1 column
   <td>16</td> // 1 row digit of 2 column
   <td>17</td> // 1 row digit of 3 column

 </tr>
 <tr> 
   <td>22</td> // 2 row digit of 1 column
   <td>23</td> // 2 row digit of 2 column 
   <td>24</td> // 2 row digit of 3 column 

 </tr>
 <tr> 
   <td>35</td> // 3 row digit of 1 column
   <td>33</td> // 3 row digit of 2 column 
   <td>32</td> // 3 row digit of 3 column 
 </tr>


</table>
```

Here first column contains following value

```
10
15
22
35
Ans:
```

Here 2nd column contains following value

```
20
16
23
33
Ans
```

Here 3rd column contains following value

```
30
17
24
32
Ans
```

I want to display it in php. Here is my php code.

```
 <table border="1px">

<?php
for($row=0;$row<3;$row++){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <?php
    for($cols=0;$cols<3;$cols++){

        ?>
        <td><?php echo $cols; ?></td>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
    <?php

    }

?>
</table>
```

Here is the output of it

```
0   1   2
0   1   2
0   1   2
```

But i required

```
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
```

Why? how can i make this correctly?

Comment: By putting the tr tags in the right place outside the inner loop

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen how i will add these value eg. 10
15
22
35
Ans-

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code and move `tr`/ `/tr` outside second `for` loop:

```
<table>
<?php
for($row=0;$row<3;$row++){?>
    <tr>  <!-- Open tr here -->
    <?php
    for($cols=0;$cols<3;$cols++){?>
        <td><?php echo rand(0, 10); ?></td>
    <?php
    }?>
    </tr>  <!-- Close tr here -->
<?php
    }?>
</table>
```

Comment: what about the sum of first, second and third column.

Comment: Store generated values in array and count required sum.

Comment: here is my output after it                                                                                  
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2                                                                                                        
But result required is                                                                                            0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 2

Comment: `echo $rows;` then.

Comment: i make some changes will you please check again.